# Google App Engine app.yaml configuration for /user/.* regex

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, app.yaml

I'm trying to make a login and profile page. Here is the app.yaml file which works fine for '/' and '/(anything)'. Instead of '/(anything)' I would like to have the path as '/user/.*'. I tried a lot but it only renders the html part of the page.  How do I configure my app.yaml, so that it renders with complete CSS and JS and works for '/(anything)/(anything)'?

```
application: My-App-name
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes


handlers:
- url: /(.*\.css)
  mime_type: text/css
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.css)

- url: /(.*\.html)
  mime_type: text/html
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.html)

- url: /(.*\.js)
  mime_type: text/javascript
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.js)

 image files
- url: /(.*\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))

# index files
- url: /(.+)/
  static_files: static/\1/index.html
  upload: static/(.+)/index.html


# site root

- url: /.*
  script: main.app

#- url: /user/.*
#  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

PS: I have my folder tree as,

app.yaml

static->CSS,JS,Images,html files

index.yaml
main.app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
- url: /(.+)/(.*\.js)
  mime_type: text/javascript
  static_files: static/\2
  upload: static/(.*\.js)
```

This will match `/anything/file.js` as well as `/anything/anything/file.js`, as well as `/junk/static/hellothere/this/matches/everything/file.js`, because (.+) also matches all the slashes.  If you don't want it to match both, then you need to handle the slashes in the regex (separate handling for characters and slashes):

```
- url: /([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/(.*\.js)
  mime_type: text/javascript
  static_files: static/\3
  upload: static/(.*\.js)
```

This matches `/any-thing/any_th-ing/file.js`.  If you want to get more specific, you can use:

```
- url: /user/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/(.*\.js)
  mime_type: text/javascript
  static_files: static/\2
  upload: static/(.*\.js)
```

to match `/user/anything/file.js', or:

```
- url: /([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/static/(.*\.js)
  mime_type: text/javascript
  static_files: static/\2
  upload: static/(.*\.js)
```

to match `/anything/static/file.js`

Comment: Hey buddy , what is use of the upload parameter ? I mean right now I am using Django and I have ran collectstatic to collect all the files in one place. SO will it be uploaded via gcloud or server will run the command automatically ?

Comment: it's not working can you help me with my problem ? I have posted a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48849370/app-yaml-file-configuration-for-static-files-in-django-in-google-app-engine , I have done exactly you have told here to do , One thing I want to ask the the app.yaml and static folder should be in the same directory ?