# App Engine app.yaml variable subdirectories

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, angular-universal

Here's my current app.yaml:

```
runtime: nodejs10
service: default

instance_class: F1
automatic_scaling:
  min_instances: 0
  max_instances: 2

handlers:

  # Serve extension from where they were requested
- url: /(.*\.(css|ico|js|png|jpg|gif|mp4|txt|xml|json))$
  static_files: dist/apps/my-app/browser/\1
  upload: dist/apps/my-app/browser/.*\.(css|ico|js|png|jpg|gif|mp4|txt|xml|json)$
  secure: always
  expiration: "365d"

  # Handle blog SEO routes
- url: /blog
  static_files: dist/apps/my-app/browser/blog/index.html
  upload: dist/apps/my-app/browser/blog/index.html
  secure: always
  expiration: "0s"

- url: /blog/introducing-my-app
  static_files: dist/apps/my-app/browser/blog/introducing-my-app/index.html
  upload: dist/apps/my-app/browser/blog/introducing-my-app/index.html
  secure: always
  expiration: "0s"

- url: /blog/added-international-support
  static_files: dist/apps/my-app/browser/blog/added-international-support/index.html
  upload: dist/apps/my-app/browser/blog/added-international-support/index.html
  secure: always
  expiration: "0s"

- url: /blog/new-blog-entry
  static_files: dist/apps/my-app/browser/blog/new-blog-entry/index.html
  upload: dist/apps/my-app/browser/blog/new-blog-entry/index.html
  secure: always
  expiration: "0s"

  # Handle default index.html
- url: /(.*)
  static_files: dist/apps/my-app/browser/index.html
  upload: dist/apps/my-app/browser/index.html
  secure: always
  expiration: "0s"
```

How can I combine the rules under "Handle blog SEO routes" in to one rule? Updating app.yaml with every blog entry is not scalable.

This structure is generated from an Angular Universal Prerender project.

I have tried a few combinations with no luck:

```
- url: /blog/(.*)
  static_files: dist/apps/my-app/browser/blog/\1/index.html
  upload: dist/apps/my-app/browser/blog/\1/index.html
  secure: always
  expiration: "0s"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your last try is very close to the actual solution. Please, simply adjust the `upload` value:

```yaml
- url: /blog/(.*)
  static_files: dist/apps/my-app/browser/\1/index.html
  upload: dist/apps/my-app/browser/(.*)/index.html
  secure: always
  expiration: "0s"
```

As you can see in the [Google Cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_element) when describing the `upload` key, you need to provide regex placeholders and not back references in its definition.

Please, consider review similar question here in SO like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25346266/google-app-engine-app-yaml-configuration-for-user-regex) or [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22194876/how-to-regex-for-static-webpage-on-google-app-engine).